# Asus 501JW computer wont start

Tags: bios, usb-flash-drive, power

I have an ASUS ROG 501JW, I put it to sleep and after trying to wake it up, the ASUStek application said it was erasing everything from the flash drive, panicking at the imminent loss of information, I turned it off from the power button. Now the computer won't turn on or even charge. I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you interrupted a bios update process - as the flash where it's stored (not the drive) needs to be erased before it's rewritten. There is no way to repair the laptop without access to external programmer, you need to RMA it and it will be reflashed (warranty may cover bad flash, but not damage caused by user - YMMV).